# Is it correct to say "speaking off-topic"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Is the following sentence right:

> speaking off-topic about ordinary everyday problems not only can
>   distract the students but also wastes a lot of time.

I want to know if using the phrase "off-topic" is ok here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of "off-topic" is fine, but the lack of parallelism in your choice of verbs is a bit jarring. Would the following sentence be an acceptable alternative? **Speaking off-topic about everyday problems and ordinary concerns not only distracts other students but also wastes a lot of time.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it is better, in my opinion, to just delete it. Your sentence and your message is understood without it.

Comment: And I'd put a comma between ordinary and everyday unless you are, in principle, using ordinary as an adverb.